# why does it keep showing that a code is undefined in JOptionPane?

Tags: java, swing, undefined, joptionpane

I am a begginner and i am trying to run this code but it keeps showing problems
This is my code:

```
package detyra:
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Vendingmachine{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     
        String response;
        int dollarbills,stamps,change;
        response=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Dollarbill");
        dollarbills=int.parsedouble(response);
        stamps=dollarbills/47;
        change=dollarbills%47;      
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Dollar bill:"
            + dollarbills + "\nStamps:" +stamps +"\nChange:"  +change);                           
    }
}
```

And these are the problems:

```
The method showInputDialog(null, String) is undefined for the type JOptionPane  JOptionPane.java    /detyra/src/javax/swing line 13 Java Problem
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The method showInputDialog(null, String) is undefined for the type JOptionPane  Vendingmachine.java /detyra/src/detyra  line 10 Java Problem
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The method showMessageDialog(null, String) is undefined for the type JOptionPane    JOptionPane.java    /detyra/src/javax/swing line 18 Java Problem
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The method showMessageDialog(null, String) is undefined for the type JOptionPane    Vendingmachine.java /detyra/src/detyra  line 15 Java Problem
```

Comment: `/detyra/src/javax/swing` definitely doesn't sound right. Did you write your own `JOptionPane` class? That should be imported from the Java standard library, not from your own project repo.

Comment: First of all make sure to use a java version or lib  where swing components are still a part of. Then check the documentation and there you can see that 2 possible methods can match the param types: null, String which means null, object. since everything is a object.
So there are 2 methods that are colliding with the 2 very general param types since NULL can be anything and the other are wrapped at object. You need to be more precise so java can choose 1.

Check here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html

Comment: @LenglBoy Both aspects of your comment are incorrect / misleading. swing is part of all distros (it's javafx you're thinking of - that is a dep you sometimes have to pull in). This error indicates it cannot be an overload issue.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Looks like the project is getting compiled with the wrong classpath. Check your IDE/Project settings or how else you run the compiler.

Comment: It looks like you've written your first attempt in a class that you've called `JOptionPane`, which conflicts with the one belonging to the Java API. You then created a new class with a new name `VendingMachine` but unfortunately you left your `JOptionPane` class behind, and the compiler is looking at that one instead of the Java Swing class. Delete (or rename) your `JOptionPane` class and you should be able to proceed. And next time, don't name any of your packages starting with the word "java".